# Synonym for 'overly obvious'?

Tags: academic-writing, word-choice

Writing about Waugh. Nanny Hawkins is first described thus:
'her hands lay open in her lap and, loosely between then, a rosary; she was fast asleep'.
I find the rosary reference to be TOO blatant, superfluous, redundant... what can I call it other than 'overly-obvious'?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Requests for single words are not on-topic for us, but they are at English SE. I have flagged the mods to migrate your question.

Comment: This sounds like peeving in the form of a question, which is likely to be closed on EL&U.SE as well.

Comment: For this question "self-evident" seems too restrained.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Do you want to reword that description somehow, or are you commenting on it and looking for a word to describe your reaction?  What is "obvious" (overly or otherwise) about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word 'obvious' doesn't really have degrees; something is generally obvious or it's not. What you might be looking for:

> flagrant: shockingly noticeable or evident
>
> ostentatious: intended to attract notice
>
> glaring: very conspicuous or obvious

Answer (score 0):

"On the nose" might work, though the phrase isn't all that well known outside of Hollywood. Unsubtle?